# stuck on current location - iphone sdk

Tags: iphone, core-location

I'm trying to get the current location using the iphone sdk.  Here is the code:

http://pastie.org/572062

here is the error on build:

Building target “Send2iPhone” of project “Send2iPhone” with configuration “Release” — (2 errors)
        cd /Users/pswenson/dev/send2iphone/iphone_code/Send2iPhone
    setenv MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET 10.5
    setenv PATH "/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
    /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/gcc-4.2 -arch i386 -isysroot /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator3.1.sdk -L/Users/pswenson/dev/send2iphone/iphone_code/Send2iPhone/build/Release-iphonesimulator -F/Users/pswenson/dev/send2iphone/iphone_code/Send2iPhone/build/Release-iphonesimulator -filelist /Users/pswenson/dev/send2iphone/iphone_code/Send2iPhone/build/Send2iPhone.build/Release-iphonesimulator/Send2iPhone.build/Objects-normal/i386/Send2iPhone.LinkFileList -mmacosx-version-min=10.5 -framework Foundation -framework UIKit -framework CoreGraphics -o /Users/pswenson/dev/send2iphone/iphone_code/Send2iPhone/build/Release-iphonesimulator/Send2iPhone.app/Send2iPhone
Undefined symbols:
  ".objc_class_name_CLLocationManager", referenced from:
      literal-pointer@__OBJC@__cls_refs@CLLocationManager in DetailViewController.o
  "_kCLLocationAccuracyNearestTenMeters", referenced from:
      _kCLLocationAccuracyNearestTenMeters$non_lazy_ptr in DetailViewController.o
ld: symbol(s) not found
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
          ".objc_class_name_CLLocationManager", referenced from:
              literal-pointer@__OBJC@__cls_refs@CLLocationManager in DetailViewController.o
          "_kCLLocationAccuracyNearestTenMeters", referenced from:
              _kCLLocationAccuracyNearestTenMeters$non_lazy_ptr in DetailViewController.o
        ld: symbol(s) not found
        collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
Build failed (2 errors)

I'm clueless.... any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you added the CoreLocation library to your project?  Looks like your having problems linking, which usually means you don't have all the libraries your project needs.

Comment: Yeah, that was it.  I had a hell of a time getting XCode to recognize the framework though, but eventually it worked.

Thanks!